# Jenkins Dotnet Project Publishing Issue

Tags: asp.net, powershell, jenkins, devops

I am trying to publish my dotnet project-api from jenkins via powershell. The problem is when I publish it from powershell it's missing around 30 files and I can't reach api. However when I publish it from visual studio manually (or from visual studio package manager console with commands) it works perfectly. What might be causing this issue?

Here are the commands that I am running to publish api ;

```
dotnet restore 
dotnet build --configuration release
dotnet publish -c release --output "path to the publish file"
```

I have also tried with this to publish command yet it didn'T work;

> `dotnet publish dotnet publish -c Release --self-contained -r win10-x64`

I have been trying to figure this issue for a long time but I couldn't find a way. I would highly appreciate any help. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You should try following 2 Execute Windows batch command

1. Command

   "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" restore yourProjectSLN file

   [E.g:yourProjectSLN = git/FolderName/ProjectName.sln , it should be same as jenkins configuration]
2. Command

   dotnet publish yourProject_csproj_file_location -c:Release

   [E.g:yourProject_csproj_file_location =  git\FolderName\ProjectName.csproj]